# SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol [connection to msa (587) port]

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp, smtpclient

I am trying to send email when a new user registrates or forgot his password.
I am working on a linux and the app was developed with node.js.

Error:

```
[Error: 140020013401920:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:

014-03-17T04:23:22-0700 app.0: debug: cleared heartbeat timeout for client VP5heQmQKpirWe81qegF
2014-03-17T04:23:22-0700 app.0: debug: set heartbeat interval for client VP5heQmQKpirWe81qegF
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0: { name: 'anyUser',
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0: { [Error: 140020013401920:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:683:
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:   hash: null,
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0: ] stage: 'init' }
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:   email: 'testmail@testmail.com',
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:   initial: null,
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:   _id: 5326d4262a8c57cf04000005,
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:   __v: 0,
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:   pending: false,
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:   playerBadges: [],
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:   appRole: 'Player',
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:   projectsPlayer:
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:    [ { project: 5326d366c004dd9305000005,
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:        _id: 5326d4262a8c57cf04000006,
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0:        role: 'Team Member' } ] }
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0: PUT /login/resetpassword 200 4ms - 58
2014-03-17T04:23:28-0700 app.0: notify client side that there are a error send  email
2014-03-17T04:23:47-0700 app.0: debug: emitting heartbeat for client VP5heQmQKpirWe81qegF
2014-03-17T04:23:47-0700 app.0: debug: websocket writing 2::
```

Configuration:

```
var smtp = {
  host: "server.stestmail.local",
  secureConnection: true,
  port: 587,
  requiresAuth: false,
  domains: ["stestmail.com"],
  auth: {
    user: "anyuser@stestmail.com",
    pass: ""
  }
```

I don't know why I get that error.

Comment: Are you sure that that is a proper configuration?  You don't need a password for the mail server in order to send or connect?  Have you redacted it or do you not use one?

Comment: I tried with a valid user and valid password as well but get same error.SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you connect to msa (587) or smtp (25) port then **DO NOT** set `secureConnection` to *true*.

Your code with `secureConnection` set to true tries to start SSL negotiation at once but the other side gives you *unencrypted* SMTP greeting.

https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

> **secureConnection** - use SSL (default is false, not needed with service). If you're using port 587 then keep secureConnection false, since the connection is started in insecure plain text mode and only later upgraded with STARTTLS